# jQuery Hiding and Unhiding a div with one button

Tags: jquery, syntax

```
if (p5goback = true)
    {
        $("#p5-6").fadeOut("slow");
        p5goback = false;   
    }
else    
    {
        $("#p5-6").fadeIn("slow");
        var p5goback = true;
    }
```

Using the above code i would like to be able to use one button to hide and unhidden a div.

The above code doesn't appear to be working, any ideas why?

I don't believe the HTML is needed, but if you would like a jsfiddle leave a comment.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is assigning, not checking. Use `==` for comparison:

```
if(p5goback == true) { ... }
```

Since `p5goback` is a boolean, you can leave out the `== true` part entirely:

```
if(p5goback) { ... }
```

Since you're always setting `p5goback` to the inverse of what it was, you might be able to get away with simply:

```
$('#p5-6').fadeToggle('slow');
p5goback = !p5goback;
```

Note that this might introduce unexpected behavior if `p5goback` (or the `#p5-6` visibility) is ever changed by anything *else* than that function (i.e. if there is any scenario where *only* `#p5-6` visibility *or* the value of the `p5goback` boolean changes)

To be sure that the state is always consistent between these two variables, you could write something like this, but readability suffers from it, and you might be better off just using the condition:

```
$.fn[ p5goback ? 'fadeOut' : 'fadeIn' ].call($('#p5-6'), 'slow');
p5goback = !p5goback;
```

The above code calls `$.fn.fadeOut` *or*  `$.fn.fadeIn`, depending on the value of `p5goback`, and then sets `p5goback` to the inverse boolean value of its current value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're inside the button.onclick method you want to use. 
Instead of fadeIn/fadeOut you can use

`$("#p5-6").toggle("slow");`

And also you need to correct your if statement: `if (p5goback == true)`

Answer (score 0):

It will be more beautiful if you use the [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) function ;)

```
 $("#p5-6").fadeToggle("slow");
```